# Scrapy stack overflow of Requests

Tags: python, python-2.7, scrapy, stack-overflow

I have the following while loop to scrap pages

```
def after_login(self, response):
    i=100000
    while (i<2000000): 
       yield scrapy.Request("https://www.example.com/foobar.php?nr="+str(i),callback=self.another_login)
       i+=1
```

The problem is that the process gets killed because of stack overflow.
Is there a way to tell the while loop to queue 1000 requests and when those are done to queue another 1000?

Comment: You are getting into infinite recursion issues. Why are you calling `self.after_login` *from a request started in `self.after_login`*?

Comment: @Martijn My mistake, fixed the question

Comment: Can you share the actual traceback you get?

Comment: @Martijn It doesn't show, the process just gets Killed by ubuntu without showing any traceback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should play around with Scrapy settings. For instance, try decreasing the [`CONCURRENT_REQUESTS`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#concurrent-requests), adding [`DOWNLOAD_DELAY`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#download-delay).

If that does not help, look into [debugging the memory usage](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#memdebug-enabled), see also:

- [Debugging memory leaks](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/leaks.html)